Как вывести текст на экран определëнного пользователя? pyTelegramBotAPI
Вот скриншот чего я хочу добиться

Хочу найти именно функцию которая высветила мне "OpenLeague Вы уже зарегистрированы".
Искал эту функцию на ютубе и в официальной документации, но так и не нашëл потому что не знаю как правильно сформулировать запрос.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
